# How to calculate the area and perimeter of a Ring using C++ Structures?

Tags: c++

How to calculate the area and perimeter of a ring using C++ Structures ?

internal:  center = (1.2, 6.5), radii = 2.8;
external:  center = (1.2, 6.5), radii = 5.4

```
struct Point
{
    float x;
    float y;
};

struct Circle
{
    Point center;
    float radii;

    float Area() { return 3.14f * radii * radii; }
    float Perimeter() { return 2.0f * 3.14f * radii; }
};

struct Ring
{
    Circle external;
    Circle internal;

    float Area() { return external.Area() - internal.Area(); }
    float Perimeter() { return external.Perimeter() + internal.Perimeter(); }
};
```

Comment: It seems your code answers your own question.

Comment: Does your code not work? Are you looking for ways to improve it? What is your real query?

Comment: In case, you struggle with a compiler error: There is a typo: `Cricle external;`.

Comment: If you are looking for a code review for this code (which compiles just fine), please go to https://codereview.stackexchange.com . Otherwise, please clarify your problem.

Comment: I have fixed the **typo: Cricle external**